# How do I archive this Swift dictionary from NSUserDefaults and send it via mail? Encoding seems garbled

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, nskeyedarchiver

I have the following code to turn `NSUserDefaults` into `NSData` and then send it with an instance of `MFMailComposeViewController`:

```
let defaultsData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation())
mailViewController.addAttachmentData(defaultsData, mimeType: "text/txt", fileName: "details.txt")
```

Pretty simple stuff, but when I send it off I get a .txt that is very garbled where it starts with this:

```
bplist00‘������òôX$versionX$objectsY$archiverT$top�Ü†Ø|���ô�ö�õ�ú�ù�û�ü�†�°�¢�£�§�•�¶�ß�®�©�™�´�¨�≠�Æ�Ø�∞�±�≤�≥�¥�µ�∂�∑�∏�π�∫�ª�º�Ω�æ�ø�¿�¡�¬�√�ƒ�≈�∆�«�»�…� �À�Ã�Õ�Œ�œ�–�—�“�”�‘�’�÷�◊�ÿ�Ÿ�⁄�€�‹�›�ﬁ�ﬂ�‡�Ï�Ì�Ó�Ô��Ò�Ú�Û�Ù�˙�˚�¸"#$)*+./367?@ABCDGJVWcfqrstuvwxy|∞±≤≥¥µ∂∑∏π∫ªºΩæø¿¡¬√ƒ≈∆«»… ÀÃÕŒœ–—“”‘’÷◊ÿŸ⁄€‹›ﬁﬂ‡·Ìıˆ˜˙¡¬√ƒ≈∆«»… ÀÃÕŒœ–—“”‘’÷◊ÿŸ⁄€‹›ﬁﬂ‡·‚„‰ÂÊÁËÈÍÎÏÌÓÔÒÚÛÙıˆ˜¯˘˙˚¸˝˛ˇ�   

 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy|ÇÉÜáäçéëíóU$null”�   �
���R�òWNS.keysZNS.objectsV$classØE�

�������������������
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed expected. The resulting NSData of NSKeyedArchiver is binary property list (`bplist`) representation of the dictionary. So you get binary data. What did you expect to receive?

Comment: The same as if I `NSLog` the dictionary: readable data without a bunch of garbled encoding.

Comment: In that case, use `description` method on `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation()`. This is what NSLog does. The result is a String and not NSData.